# Data binding - XML not updating after onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, android-databinding

Updating `ObservableField` inside `onActivityResult(..)` of `activity` but not reflecting that value to `XML`. If I call executePendingBindings() it will work. But the issue is, there are a lot of `ObservableField` and for every variable, I need to call `executePendingBindings()`.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, but in my case the binding to xml is broken at all. The reason is, that onActivityResult is called before your activity or fragment is resumed. So the state of your lifecycleowner is not at least STARTED and the binding wont be executed. See the code example of Sangeet Suresh answer. I don't know why the binding isn't executed when your lifecycleowner is RESUMED again. Maybe there is a bug?

Comment: @ThomasMeinhart I was the one who has asked this question. Then after some time, I figured out the answer and just wrote it here.

Comment: I'm sorry, i should have read till the end.

Answer (score 3):

In `ViewDataBinding.java` file, there is one method for requesting rebind

```
protected void requestRebind() {
        if (mContainingBinding != null) {
            mContainingBinding.requestRebind();
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mPendingRebind) {
                    return;
                }
                mPendingRebind = true;
            }
            if (mLifecycleOwner != null) {
                Lifecycle.State state = mLifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().getCurrentState();
                if (!state.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
                    return; // wait until lifecycle owner is started
                }
            }
            if (USE_CHOREOGRAPHER) {
                mChoreographer.postFrameCallback(mFrameCallback);
            } else {
                mUIThreadHandler.post(mRebindRunnable);
            }
        }
    }
```

When control enters that method `mPendingRebind` will be false and it will be made true by this method. `mChoreographer.postFrameCallback(mFrameCallback);` will make that variable again to false so that other bindings will update the view.

The issue was `!state.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` condition. Since ObservableField is updated from `onActivityResult(..)`, the current state will be `Lifecycle.State.CREATED` So that condition will fail and return that method without calling `mChoreographer.postFrameCallback(mFrameCallback);` and `mPendingRebind` will be true. So remaining bindings will not update.

So the solution was to call `SingleLiveEvent` and observe that variable. When that callback is received, we have to update ObservableField()

For eg :

```
val updateObserver = SingleLiveEvent<Unit>()
```

Then observe for that event

```
updateObserver.observe(this, Observer { 
            //update ObservableField
        })
```

Call that event from onActivityResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               updateObserver.call()
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a `SingleLiveEvent` and prefer to keep your callback code in `onActivityResult`, and you have a base activity where all activities extend from, you can add a `scheduleUpdateAfterOnActivityResult` method to the base activity:

```java
// When onActivityResult is run, the activity is still in Lifecycle.State.CREATED and
// bindings will not fire.  Schedule the update by creating a new MutableLiveData,
// which will fire observers when activity lifecycle is active.
// See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104670/data-binding-xml-not-updating-after-onactivityresult/53107092
public <T> void scheduleUpdateAfterOnActivityResult(T data, Observer<T> observer) {
    final MutableLiveData<T> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    liveData.observe(this, new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final T v) {
            observer.onChanged(v);
            liveData.removeObserver(this);
        }
    });
    liveData.postValue(data);
}
```

then in 
`onActivityResult` call `scheduleUpdateAfterOnActivityResult()`:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_XXXX && data != null) {
        scheduleUpdateAfterOnActivityResult(data, bundle -> {
            // do something
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: It's not working .. no change after adding this code