# Android dataBinding does not refresh ui

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I have some trouble with Android data-binding.

I have a class like this:

```
class AppConfig private constructor() : BaseObservable() {
    @Bindable
    var title = ""

    fun updateTitle(newTitle: String) {
        title = newTitle
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.title)
    }
    ......
}
```

When the app is in background, the app received an update push and function updateTitle is called. Then I turn to my app, I can see the title has changed. Then I push another update, the title doesn't change. Then I press the home button and bring the app to front again, the title is updated.

I have read the ViewDataBinding source code:

```
    protected void requestRebind() {
        if (mContainingBinding != null) {
            mContainingBinding.requestRebind();
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mPendingRebind) {
                    return;
                }
                mPendingRebind = true;
            }
            if (mLifecycleOwner != null) {
                Lifecycle.State state = mLifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().getCurrentState();
                if (!state.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
                    return; // wait until lifecycle owner is started
                }
            }
            if (USE_CHOREOGRAPHER) {
                mChoreographer.postFrameCallback(mFrameCallback);
            } else {
                mUIThreadHandler.post(mRebindRunnable);
            }
        }
    }
```

The condition `!state.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` failed at the first time, and variable `mPendingRebind` is set true. It seems that only when `mRebindRunnable` or `mFrameCallback` runs, variable `mPendingRebind` will be set false again. So the UI will  never refresh.

I've seen this issue [Data binding - XML not updating after onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104670/data-binding-xml-not-updating-after-onactivityresult). I try to use SingleLiveEvent, and I call `updateObserver.call()` in Activity's onResume. It doesn't work.

I've also tried to use reflect to set `mPendingRebind` false forcibly. It works but I think  this is not a good way. What should I do?

Comment: If I remove `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` in my fragment, `mLifecycleOwner` will be null and it works well......

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var title = ""
@Bindable get() = title
```